# Organizing Go code in repo alongside other languages

Tags: go, code-organization

What is the standard way to organize Go code in a repo that also contains scripts from other languages? It seems like you are intended to just have one directory for all of your Go projects, with source code in `go/src/project1`, `go/src/project2` etc. But it would be strange to stick a node script in `go/src/project1/node_scripts`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are storing node scripts in a Go project?  I assume you're writing your front end using node tools, the two projects can and should stand alone, communicating over API requests no?

Comment: The front end is totally separate. I have Node in the backend because there are a couple cases where I call a node script from a Go program (for these small tasks, the available Node libraries are much more developed than the comparable Go packages).

Comment: "But it would be strange to stick a node script in go/src/project1/node_scripts" Why? (Of course Node code should go to /dev/null :-)

Comment: I used to dislike this aspect of Go as well but nowadays I just `go get` every repository from Github, also non-go repositories. I like that I can clone a repository and put in a logical place (with all other repositories of the same organisation) with a single command. There is nothing wrong with that.